# Get association for the nested model in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I don't know have to get select box for the association and value from the other model.
For example i have a table `course_names` to record course name.

I have other table which has other table `course` which has more columns with `course_name_id`

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :course_name

end
```

Now, i have to create student_profile and have association for `courses` table like this.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :course
  ...
end
```

And in the view with the simple form i have to create a select box for to select course.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@student_profile) do |f|%>
    <% f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.association :course  %>
```

But this association don't show course name.

```
<select class="select optional form-control" id="student_course_id" name="student[course_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="3">#&lt;Course:0x00000105c23818&gt;</option></select>
```

But i want the output as (course-name for the option from course_names)

```
<select class="select optional form-control" id="student_course_id" name="student[course_id]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="3">course-name</option>
</select>
```

How, do i achieve this.
one, solution is

```
<%= f.association :course,collection:Course.all.includes(:course_name).map{|a|[a.course_name.name,a.id]}  %>
```

but this doesn't seem right? How do i tell association go get course name from the association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to use this : label_method like that :

```
<%= f.association :course, label_method: :course_name  %>
```

Or as course belongs to course_name, maybe you want this:

```
<%= f.association :course, label_method: lambda { |course| "#{course.course_name.name}"}  %>
```

**Edit** To avoid all the queries, you should preload the data

```
courses = Course.includes(:course_name)
```

And then use it as follow

```
<% f.association :course, collection: courses, label_method: lambda { |course| "#{course.course_name.name}" } %>
```

Comment: Yes, second option is the answer. but it gives birth to the N+1 query.